# Change a label inside a UICollectionView Cell by pressing it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

can anyone point me in the right direction of trying to edit a UiCollectionView cell by pressing on it? I have 3 labels inside a XIB, and that is presented in the UICollectionView. I would like to have the user be able to edit it when they press on a certain cell. Maybe even pop up like below.

Thanks all

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a `UITextField` instead of a `UILabel` to enable user interaction. Then link that `UITextField` to your custom `UICollectionViewCell` class.

Comment: Very true. I did not think of it like that. Thanks!